# How to use contains on a swiftyJSON object

Tags: swift, contains, swifty-json

I'm trying to use contains in swift to find a value on an array, however when I use a variable as the predicate, I get a 'String is not convertible to 'S.Generator.Element'.

Could anyone explain what that means and why is it happening?

This is the original JSON, loaded and parsed using swiftyJSON:

{
  "holidays" : [
    "01/01/2015",
    "12/01/2015",
    "23/03/2015",
    "02/04/2014",
    "03/04/2015",
    "01/05/2015",
    "18/05/2015",
    "08/06/2015",
    "15/06/2015",
    "29/06/2015",
    "20/07/2015",
    "17/08/2015",
    "12/10/2015",
    "02/11/2015",
    "16/11/2015",
    "08/12/2015",
    "25/12/2015",
    "02/01/2016"
      ]
    }

This works

```
var haystack:Array<JSON> = jsonData["holidays"].arrayValue
if(contains(haystack, "01/01/2015")) {
    return true
}
```

This does not work:

```
var haystack:Array<JSON> = jsonData["holidays"].arrayValue
var needle:String = "01/01/2015"
if(contains(haystack, needle)) {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of calling `arrayValue`, try `object`:

```
if let haystack = jsonData["holidays"].object as? [String] {
    let needle = "01/01/2015"
    if contains(haystack, needle) {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks!.  I was assuming that arrayValue would return an array like [String].  But it seems it doesn't.  When should you be using arrayValue or dictionaryValue then?

Comment: @afterxleep `arrayValue` returns `[JSON]`: Specifically it returns `map(self.object as [AnyObject]){ JSON($0) }`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should run ok, see image below, and probably you array type should be `Array<String>`.

[image]

Comment: Yea, that works, however the original array is loaded from a file using swiftyJSON, and that's why I declare it as Array<JSON> which is the JSON object returned from swiftyJSON after parsing.  When that's the case, it does not work.